# Showing Popup Windows with MVC, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, printing

I have a simple create form in MVC 4 and would like two submit functions: (1) Create and (2) Create & Print.  Create is a normal Create action and works perfectly.  Create & Print should save the object and then launch a popup browser window with data from the newly saved object.  The original window needs to refresh to a blank Create form ready for another record.

What is the best way to approach this?

Below is an example that works in practice however I have the ID hardcoded in.  Ideally, this ID will dynamically inherit from the object that was just saved and link there.  Is JavaScript the best idea here or should (can) I launch the popup from the Controller?

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
<input type="submit" 
     value="Create & Print" 
     onclick="window.open('Print/f1ad6330-2978-4ea9-9116-65f861412260'
       , 'PRINT'
       , 'height=200,width=200');" />
```

Comment: can't you save object, receive id back, and use that id to open popup?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt yes, in theory this is what I need but need help with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up bypassing the form's default submit call to the Create method and just created two new methods. It's not ideal, but it works.

**SOLUTION**

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Dummy", "Count", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
    // My Form
    // Note the Dummy controller which will just fall through and do nothing
}
```

Form Submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create & Print" onclick="createAndPrint();" />
<input type="submit" value="Create"         onclick="createWithoutPrinting();" />
```

JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function createAndPrint() {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "CreateAndPrint",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var lastInsId = data; // you will get last insert id here.
                var secWin = window.open('Print/' + lastInsId
                , 'PRINT'
                , 'height=450,width=230');
                secWin.focus();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createWithoutPrinting() {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "Create",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#form1").serialize()
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Dummy(Count count)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}

[HttpPost]
public string CreateAndPrint(Count count)
{
    SaveCount(count);

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        // Now get last insert id
        string lastInsertId = count.Id.ToString();
        return lastInsertId;
    }

    return "";
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Count count)
{
    SaveCount(count);

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        // Now get last insert id
        string lastInsertId = count.Id.ToString();
        return PartialView("_Create", lastInsertId);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to create another action which returns string (last-insert-id), post data to it through ajax and get last-insert-id back in javascript then you can use it to open new window.
Now suppose this is new controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
        public string CreateAndPrint(Object obj)
        {
           // Save data here / insert record here

           if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
           {
             // Now get last insert id
             string lastInsertId = db.GetLastInsertId; // get last insert id from database
             return lastInsertId;
            }
        }
```

Have a javascript function to post the data:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function creteAndPrint() {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "CreateAndPrint",
            type: "POST",
            data : $("#from1").serialize(),
            success:function(data) 
            {
                var lastInsId = data; // you will get last insert id here.
                var secWin = window.open('Print/'+lastInsId
                , 'PRINT'
                , 'height=200,width=200');
                secWin.focus();
            }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

And call this function only on create & print button:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Create & Print" onclick="creteAndPrint();" />
```

Hope it works for you. Thank you.

---

Here I am editing my answer after your comment :)

Yes! you can call the same `Create` action for achieving the same which I explained above. But for that you have to make some changes in the your `Create` action:

```
 public string Create(Object obj)
        {
           // Save data here / insert record here

           if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
           {
             // Now get last insert id
             string lastInsertId = db.GetLastInsertId; // get last insert id from database
             return PartialView("_Create", lastInsertId);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Notice that when you call this action through AJAX it will return a partial view, which return just LAST_INSERT_ID as string. You just have create one simple partial view `_Create` to print last-insert-id.
Partial view will have only two lines:

```
@model string
@Model
```

This will print the last-inst-id which we have passed from controller action.

Comment: This looks to be a solution however it still hits the Create method after hitting the CreateAndPrint method.  I think the Create method is the default for the form.  Is there a way to bypass Create() if CreateAndPrint() is called?  Thank you!

Comment: better yet I need the main page to hit the Create() method and not the Create(Object obj) method which saves the object that was just saved in the CreateAndPrint(Object obj) call.

Comment: @dankeshawn , Please check edited answer, forget about `CreateAndPrint` action now, just make some changes in your `Crete` action. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Request.IsAjaxRequest() did not work correctly in the normal Create(Count count) method.  It still hit this method with Request.IsAjaxRequest()=false.  Anyway, thank you for your help! I posted the working solution in your answer...  Please take a look and let me know your thoughts.